# Core Motion convert distance to KM

Tags: ios, swift, core-motion

In my Health App it says distance 0,1km, but in my app it gives me value 0.106. How can I change this to one desimal? This is the code I am using to get current stats:

```
pedometer.queryPedometerData(from: Date().startOfDay, to: Date()) { data, error in
            guard let activityData = data, error == nil else {
                print("There was an error getting the data: \(String(describing: error))")
                return
            }
            print((Double(activityData.distance!.intValue)/Double(1000))) // Print out optional distance in of walking and running in meters. / 1000 to convert from meter to km.
        }
```

> Print gives me: 0.106

Answer (score 2):

You can use Swift Measurement type to convert your length unit and MeasurementFormatter to display it to the user:

```
let number: NSNumber = 106
let measurement = Measurement(value: number.doubleValue, unit: UnitLength.meters).converted(to: .kilometers)

let mf = MeasurementFormatter()
mf.unitOptions = .providedUnit
mf.unitStyle = .medium
mf.numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 1
mf.string(from: measurement)   // "0.1 km"
```

In your case:

```
guard let value = activityData.distance?.doubleValue else { return }
let measurement = Measurement(value: value, unit: UnitLength.meters).converted(to: .kilometers)

let mf = MeasurementFormatter()
mf.unitOptions = .providedUnit
mf.unitStyle = .medium
mf.numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 1
mf.string(from: measurement)   // "0.1 km"
```

Comment: Didn't know about MeasurementFormatter before, but this makes it easy

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
let dist = Double(activityData.distance!.intValue)/Double(1000)
let str = String(format: @"%.1f", "", dist)
print(str)
```